# Unable to launch turtlebot_dashboard

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, turtlebot-dashboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I can not bring up the turtlebot_dashboard. When I try

```
 rosrun turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard
```

I get

```
Couldn't find executable named rqt below /opt/ros/groovy/share/rqt_gui
```

any idea why?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55424/unable-to-launch-turtlebot_dashboard/) by [TheSkyfall](https://answers.ros.org/users/4174/theskyfall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a bug in the current turtlebot_dashboard version. The new version contains only launchers and the new way to run the dashboard will be:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard.launch
```

(I just updated the [wiki entry](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_dashboard#Running) accordingly.)

In the meanwhile, this command should get things going for you:

```
rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui -s turtlebot_dashboard
```

Be warned, a bunch of bugs in the dashboard have been fixed in the new version (which should get into public soon), so you may run into other issues when using the current dashboard.

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1